# Floyd's Shortest Path Algorithm C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, shortest-path

I have implemented a function for Floyd's algorithm in C++ for weighted digraphs that works correctly except that, when I generate a path matrix that gives the next node when trying to reach a destination, it puts the vertex immediately before the destination instead of the next node from the source in the matrix. The distance matrix (dist) comes out correctly, and if there is at most one node between the source and destination then the whole path matrix is correct. So if there are long shortest paths from vertex i to j, then path[i][j] should equal a k value connected to i but instead its a k value connected to j and I cannot figure out why. The function is shown below.

```
void floyd(const Graph<City>& g, double**& dist, int**& path)
{
    int n = g.size();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            path[i][j]=0;
            if (i==j)
                dist[i][j]=0;
            else if (!g.isEdge(i, j))
                dist[i][j]=INFINITY;
            else
                dist[i][j]=g.retrieveEdge(i, j);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
            {
                if ((dist[i][k]!=INFINITY) && (dist[k][j]!=INFINITY) && k!=i && k!=j && i!=j)
                {
                    if ((dist[i][j]) > (dist[i][k]+dist[k][j]))
                    {
                        path[i][j]=k;
                        dist[i][j]=dist[i][k]+dist[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First use your debugger to see where in the code it deviates from the design you envisioned.  Second, faking 1-based arrays in C++ is a dangerous game -- it could lead to off-by-one memory overwrites.

Comment: Using a base 1 array just caused a few wasted places in memory, I made sure to watch out for issues there, but using the debugger I was only able to find that it must be how I'm overwriting path[i][j]. It's being overwritten with the improper values sometimes and no matter what I do I'm not seeing why.

Comment: If values are being overwritten for "no reason", then the 1-based arrays could be the cause of it.  Again, using 1-based arrays are a major reason for memory overwrites or in some cases, inadvertent usage of element 0 where element 0 is a garbage value (but not an illegal memory access).

Comment: Not for no reason. Just incorrectly. They should be overwritten with the next node from the source along the path instead of the node immediately before the destination along the path to the destination.

Comment: Well use the debugger and see why that part of the code is doing what it's doing.  We don't have a [mcve], so we cannot compile and run anything.

Comment: One would expect the answer to Floyd's Shortest path would be something like, "Tear down the wall!"

Answer (score 0):

> So if there are long shortest paths from vertex i to j, then path[i][j] should equal a k value connected to i but instead its a k value connected to j and I cannot figure out why.

Unfortunately no to both. There is nothing in your implementation that guarantees that `path[i][j]` should equal a `k` value that comes immediately after `i`, and your observation that `path[i][j]` is currently a `k` value that comes immediately before `j` is also incorrect. (Please try a few more samples to verify the second point.)

The only thing that is guaranteed by your implementation is that the vertex `path[i][j] == k` lies *somewhere* in the shortest path from vertex `i` to vertex `j`.

Thus you can retrieve the path recursively by doing:

```
get_path(i, j):
    k = path[i][j]
    get_path(i, k) + k + get_path(k, j)
```

Having clarified that, [there does exist a method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction) where you can store `path[i][j]` such that it is the vertex that comes immediately after `i`.